# Let's Encrypt certificate binds to router and not my site

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, lets-encrypt

On windows server 2008 r2 I installed a ssl certificate (Let'sEncrypt) using Certify The Web application. 
The certificate installs ok.

However when I try and view my site in ISS I get the error that the certificate issued is not for my site but other.However the bindings are configured right.
If I try and open my site from outside I get my router (FRITZ!Box) homepage. With warning of course that the connection is not encrypted.
What am I missing here ? How do I make my SSL work?

I can not set forwarding to port 443 on my router to my server because " The port forwarding cannot be created or enabled, because the port is already in use for remote maintenance (HTTPS) (Internet / Permit Access / FRITZ!Box Services)."

Comment: `I can not set forwarding to port 443 on my router to my server because " The port forwarding cannot be created or enabled, because the port is already in use for remote maintenance (HTTPS) (Internet / Permit Access / FRITZ!Box Services)."` - Well, you need to port forward port 443 to the server and disable remote management/maintenance on the router.

Comment: I disabled remote access to fritzbox. Forwarded to server . I get : 1XX.1XX.1XX.XX uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for eureka.si Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN. The domain is right. Bindings too.

Answer (score 1):

Since router was listening to SSL on 443 I assigned it another number and 443 I gave to my site on the server. Works !